# Jquery Validate minlength with depends not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate the length of input based on the value of a drop down. I cannot get it to work when I add a depends to the minlength, but it does work with a fixed value. This works :

```
CardNumber: {
  required: {
    depends: function(element){ 
      return $('input[name=PaySelect]:checked').val() == "0";
    }
  }, 
  minlength: 14
},
```

But this does not :

```
CardNumber: {
  required: {
    depends: function(element){ 
      return $('input[name=PaySelect]:checked').val() == "0";
    }
  }, 
  minlength: {
    depends: function(element){
      var paymeth = $('select[name="PayMethod"]').val();
      if (paymeth == 'American Express') {
        return 14;
      } else {
        return 16;
      }
    }
  }
},
```

If I put alert(); in I can see the code firing, but on the page it never warns the user that their input is too short and it allows the page to proceed onwards. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove `depends` from `minlength` property, as minlength returns minimum number of characters required, you can directly check your conditions and return appropriate number directly, like:

```
...
minlength: function () {
    var paymeth = $('select[name="PayMethod"]').val();
    if (paymeth == 'American Express') {
        return 14;
    } else {
        return 16;
    }
}
```